# GWT UI Issue with UiField and Text Box

Tags: gwt

**Concept**

When a user clicks a removeUser label, a text box pops up. Then, the user enters the username of the user they'd like to remove. Then, the user hits "Enter" to remove the user.

**GWT Problem**

I'm working with a class that implements an object of type, `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite.`

One of its fields includes a @UiField Label:

```
@UiField
Label removeUser;
```

And I've got a regular TextBox that should appear when the removeUser Label gets clicked.

```
 private TextBox removeUserTextBox = new TextBox();
```

If my code is correct, then the removeUserTextBox will appear when removeUser gets clicked.

```
   removeUser.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
    {
        public void onClick(final ClickEvent event)
        {   
            removeUserTextBox.setVisible(true);
            removeUserTextBox.setText("blah blah")
            removeUserTextBox.addStyleName(StaticResourceBundle.
INSTANCE.coreCss().removeUserTextBox());
            }
        });
```

However, the removeUserTextBox does not show up when I click the removeUser label.

I don't think (or know) if it's a CSS problem since removeUserTextBox's CSS is similar to removeUser's CSS, which appears correctly.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

Why are you adding a style to the textbox in the handler? Simply setVisible(true) on click, and then setVisible(false) when a user confirms the deletion.

Comment: I want the TextBox next to the RemoveUser label, so I used style to place the TextBox accordingly. Is this wrong?

Comment: Typically you add a style in Ui:Binder or when you create a widget, and not in a click handler. If your CSS does not have visibility rules, then the problem must be with attaching the textbox to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your textbox is not attached to the DOM. You may do either of following.

1) Include a textBox in a markup (uiBinder) and inject it with a @UiField annotation.

2) Add a textBox created with constructor to the RootPanel or other container which is already attached to the DOM.

3) Wrap a textBox into a popup panel and show it relative to a label. I like this variant most because there is no need in positioning with css.